# Which Destop notifier does daemons like net manager use in linux?

Tags: linux, notifications, gtk, daemon, libnotify

I am trying to show notification messages from my desktop background application using notify-send command. But I came to know that it won't work across the users i.e I am running my daemon as a root user and notify-send is not showing any notification. When I run my daemon as a non-root user, notify-send working as expected. Is there any way that notify-send works irrespective of users.And How the standard daemons like net-manager in Ubuntu shows the notifications on desktop when internet is connected or disconnected, though they run by root user ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by across users. What behavior are you not getting, and under which conditions? I can point you toward the software libraries to use instead in your programs, but this sounds weird :/

Comment: I logged into my system as a normal user and I fired "notify-send Message" command.It showed pop-up at bottom of my screen. When I fire "sudo notify-send Message" it doesn't show any pop-up.This is because notify-send communicates through dbus session bus.If this is the case then daemons in linux like network-manager which are started by root user("sudo Netmanger") still shows the pop-up on my screen(logged in as normal user). How this is possible ? what libraries they use to notify ?